# Trying To Organize Folders - Can I Delete?

Tags: windows, documents, my-documents

Had to get a new laptop and it came loaded with Windows 7.

How many folders do I need that have "documents" in the title?  I've spent days trying to get answers to questions and running into forums that tell me how to delete a folder, then spending a great deal of time giving me a sales job on why I shouldn't want to do this because these new features are great.

I want to put `My Documents` (and only one of them) under `C:`.  I want to put `My pictures` (and only one of them) under `C:`.  It should be obvious to anyone who has to maintain their own system, and they are the only person using that machine, why one would want to do that.

I don't want to move `My Documents` over to `D:` and pretend it is the only folder on my system with that name.

I found out how to delete `Public`, and that worked out fine.  I tried to move `My Documents` out from under `Users` and put it under `C:`, but it would not let me do that.  Probably because there are so many folders with that same name scattered throughout the system.

Comment: Try http://headstrongfarm.hubpages.com/hub/Windows-7_-_Moving_My_Documents. You're probably trying to move the Documents Library. BTW, deleting the Public folder was an iffy move, and it doesn't affect what you see with your own account. Also, why have C:\My Documents? What's so bad about the existing structure?